# Learning Linked Lists

Tags: c

For this lab I am working on, when I print the list, the order and ages are correct, but the name for every element is "quit". Any idea how to resolve this? I know it is quite lengthy, but some of it may be essential to my problem(not sure which).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    struct person *next;
} Person;

Person *addFront(Person *List, char *Name, int Age) {// add at front, for 
people under 21

    Person *ptrNew=malloc(sizeof(Person));
    ptrNew->name=Name;
    ptrNew->age=Age;
    ptrNew->next=List;
    return ptrNew; 
}
Person *addRear(Person *List, char *Name, int Age) { // add at rear, for 
people 21 or older

    Person *ptrNew=malloc(sizeof(Person));
    ptrNew->name=Name;
    ptrNew->age=Age;
    ptrNew->next=List;
    if (List==NULL) return ptrNew;
    Person *ptr;
    for (ptr=List; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
            if (ptr->next==NULL) break;
    }
    ptr->next=ptrNew;
    return List; 
}
void print(Person *List) {              // print the list (name and age for 
each item)
    Person *ptr;
    for (ptr=List; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
            printf("Name:%s Age:%d\n", ptr->name, ptr->age);
    }
}
void printLast(Person *List) {              // print the last person (and 
age) in the list
    Person *ptr;
        for (ptr=List; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
            if (ptr->next==NULL) printf("Name:%s Age:%d\n", ptr->name, ptr-
>age);
}
void printFirst(Person *List) {              // print the first person (and 
age) in the list
    Person *ptr=List;
    printf("Name:%s Age:%d\n", ptr->name, ptr->age);
}
int size(Person *List) {                     // return the length of the 
list
    Person *ptr;
    int count=0;
    for (ptr=List; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) count++;
    return count;
}
int inList(Person *List, char *Name) {           // returns 1 if the name is 
in the list, else 0
    Person *ptr;
    for (ptr=List; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
            if (strcmp(Name, ptr->name)==0) return 1;
            else return 0;
    }

}
int getAge(Person *List, char *Name) {           // returns the age of the 
person specified
    Person *ptr;
    for (ptr=List; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
            if (strcmp(Name, ptr->name)==0) printf("%d", ptr->age);
            else return -1;
    }

}
                          // return -1 if the person is not in the list
int main(void) {
Person *myList = NULL;
int theAge;
char theName[128];
printf("Enter the name of a person and an age (an integer) : ");
scanf("%s %d", theName, &theAge);
while ( strcmp(theName, "quit") != 0) {
    if (theAge < 21)
        myList = addFront(myList, theName, theAge);
    else
        myList = addRear(myList, theName, theAge);
    printf("Enter another name and age (or \"quit\" and any integer when done) : ");
    scanf("%s %d", theName, &theAge);
}
printf("\n\n\nThe list is " );  print(myList);
printf("\n\nThe list has %d elements\n\n", size(myList) );
printf("\nThe first person in the list (and their age) is : "); printFirst(myList);
printf("\nThe last person in the list (and their age) is :  "); printLast(myList);
printf("\n\n");
printf("Enter the name of a person (or \"exit\" to exit) : ");
scanf("%s", theName);
while ( strcmp(theName, "exit") != 0) {
    if ( inList(myList, theName) )
        printf("\tFound %s (age is %d)\n", theName, getAge(myList, theName) );
    else
        printf("\t%s was not found in the list\n", theName);
    printf("\nEnter the name of a person (or \"exit\" to exit) : ");
    scanf("%s", theName);
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addFront` and `addRear` you are using

```
ptrNew->name=Name;
```

You cannot just assign the pointer for `name` in the list to the pointer that you are reading from scanf. What happens in this case is the every `List->name` will point to the same location and if `Name` (from scanf) changes (in your case to "quit" as the last element. every `List->name` will give "quit"

What you need to do, is to allocate memory for each name separately.

```
ptrNew->name=malloc(strlen(Name)+1);
strcpy(ptrNew->name, Name);
```

Or, you can change the structure definition to store an array in name of sufficient length

```
typedef struct person {
    char name[20];
    int age;
    struct person *next;
} Person;
```

in which case you can skip the malloc step above, but the `strcpy`  is still required.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ptrNew->name` as character pointer and it always points to `theName` variable from `main()`. So all nodes in linked list points to same name.

Rather you should change code in `addFront()` and `addRear()` to

```
ptrNew->name= strdup(Name);
```

Instead of

```
ptrNew->name=Name;
```

Make sure you `free` the memory appropriately when you are done with the node.